# OfficeWebApps Server Watch Dog Error

Tags: office-web-apps, office-integration

When I link SharePoint 2013 to my WAC Server 2013 and try to preview a Word doc I get

> Sorry, this document cannot be previewed.

I have the zone to external https, Exchange and lLnc work with the WAC Srv, just not SharePoint 2013.

When I look in Event Viewer and under Microsoft Web Application I get an Event ID 1009.

> BroadcastServicesWatchdog_Wfe reported status for BroadcastServices_Host in category '4'. Reported status: Contacting Present_2_0.asmx failed with an exception: There was no endpoint listening at http://offapp1/m/Present_2_0.asmx that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.